# Idapython - undefining an instruction

Tags: ida, idapython

I have an instructions defined from `address+1` onward and a byte at `address`. I'd like to undefine the instructions from `address+1` onward and redefine them from `address` using `MakeCode` or something similar.

So far I have not found any functions to undefine instructions. Any pointers on where I should be looking?

Comment: MakeUnkn() (see http://www.offensivecomputing.net/papers/IDAPythonIntro.pdf page 48) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: In versions > 7.4 of IDA some functions have been moved (https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_no_bc695_porting_guide.shtml). The `MakeUnkn` function has been moved/renamed to `ida_bytes.del_items`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a POC from some code I wrote a while back.

```
def fixTheJmpCalls():
    # kind of slow to loop through all the functions and instructions but it works 
    # flaw: only defined functions will be traversed.this. 
    for funcea in Functions( SegStart( here() ), SegEnd( here() ) ):
        for eai in FuncItems(funcea):
            if GetMnem(eai) == "jmp" or GetMnem(eai) == "call":
                if GetDisasm(eai)[-2:-1] == "+" and GetDisasm(eai)[-1:].isdigit():
                    print "Broken Instruction: %X"%eai, GetDisasm(eai)
                    code_addr = GetOperandValue(eai, 0) 
                    fix_addr = code_addr -1 
                    MakeUnkn(fix_addr,1)
                    MakeCode(code_addr)
```